# beamer.cls and preview.sty don't work together

Tags: beamer, preview

I have the following file, in which I use the `preview` package and the `beamer` class

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{align*}
\PreviewEnvironment*{frame}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Some text and 
  \begin{align*}
    x &= y\\
    \beta &= \gamma
  \end{align*}
  a displayed equation.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If I ask for generation of previews inside `XEmacs` all is well,

[image]

but when it comes to generating the PDF...

```
$ pdflatex beamer+previev.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 ...
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01> ...
Document Class: beamer 2013/12/02 3.33 ...
(./beamer+previev.aux) ...
(/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/preview/preview.sty) ...
...
! Undefined control sequence.
\@EveryShipout@Output ...EveryShipout@Org@Shipout 
                                                  \box \@cclv 
l.16 \end{frame}


Overfull \vbox (200.87663pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
! Undefined control sequence.
\@EveryShipout@Output ...EveryShipout@Org@Shipout 
                                                  \box \@cclv 
l.17 \end{document}


Overfull \vbox (200.87663pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
! Undefined control sequence.
\@EveryShipout@Output ...EveryShipout@Org@Shipout 
                                                  \box \@cclv 
l.17 \end{document}

! Undefined control sequence.
\@EveryShipout@Output ...EveryShipout@Org@Shipout 
                                                  \box \@cclv 
l.17 \end{document}


Overfull \vbox (200.87663pt too high) has occurred while \output is active

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 1.0pt have occurred.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
...
$
```

By the way, if I remove the lines

```
\usepackage{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{align*}
\PreviewEnvironment*{frame}
```

I can compile the PDF without any problem, but when I ask for the generation of the inline preview in the `XEmacs` buffer I get only the warning

```
 LaTeX found no preview images
```

in the minibuffer and no image is inserted.

Is there any incantation that I can use to reconcile `beamer` and `preview` ways of life?

As a matter of fact, I've just installed `preview.sty` and all the stuff `auctex` related this morning, the version is `auctex-11.88`, while `beamer` is a bit oldish, but
I experienced the same misbehaviour with 11.87 while two (or three?) years ago everything was fine, so this can be a regression I don't know on which side of the barricade...

Comment: The whole preview bundle hasn't been essentially touched in the last 8 years or so.

Comment: In addition, why do you want to load `preview`?  Do you use it just to produce preview snipetts in AUCTeX?  It's useless in that case to load the package.

Comment: @giordano I need to load `preview` if I want a preview in the editor, I need to load not `preview` if I want to produce the slides... Anyway I found a solution in a thread I started on the auctex mailing list and was revived like 7 months later, when I was no more following the list! I'm going to write an answer to myself

Comment: I repeat, you don't need to load the package for the preview to work in AUCTeX.  It's never needed at all (AUCTeX creates an auxiliary file which automatically loads the package).  If it's not the case for you, there is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

While I was trying to answer [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232862/beamer-cls-and-preview-sty-dont-work-together?noredirect=1#comment551294_232862) by [giordano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/31416/giordano) I thought that I had made similar remarks in [a thread that I started in the AUCTeX mailing list](http://git.net/auctex-gnu/msg03687.html) almost exactly one years ago, so I searched that old thread to cite some parts of it and, surprise! I noticed that the thread was revived in November, 7 months later, by Nicolas Richard that advanced an hypotesis on the reason of the problem and later diagnosed the exact patch to `pgf` that caused the problem, finding also another patch that fixed it...

Loyal to SX mantra that links are not good answer, I'll report here [the link](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/316/) content (the **correct** patch is due to [`Esseger`](http://sourceforge.net/u/esseger/))

> As in the previous bug (315), this is due to the wrong patch of preview. The hack in pfgutil-latex.def, to make preview compatible with everyshi, is:

```
% Preview hack: preview.sty hacks into \shipout (which is ok), but
% does not honour everyshi.sty (which is not ok). This causes
% everyshi material to get lost.
\AtBeginDocument{
\@ifpackageloaded{preview}{%
% Ok, package loaded. Swap definitions of everyshi.sty's shipout
% and preview.sty's shipout:
\let\pgf@temp\pr@shipout% This is the original shipout
\let\pr@shipout\@EveryShipout@Shipout%
\let\@EveryShipout@Org@Shipout\pgf@temp%
}{}%
}
```

> There are two problems with this patch:
>      - it does not work if preview is loaded but not active (see bug 315)
>      - it does not set \shipout correctly. Indeed, preview has to cancel the shipout of usual pages, so it sets \shipout to a fancy version of "do nothing". But everyshi sets again \shipout to something non-trivial, so usual pages are again output, giving rise to too many pages. So, the patch should again empty \shipout.
>      Here is a correct patch:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
\@ifpackageloaded{preview}{%
% Ok, package loaded. Swap definitions of everyshi.sty's shipout
% and preview.sty's shipout:
\ifPreview
\let\shipout\@EveryShipout@Org@Shipout%This is the null version of \shipout, created by preview and saved by everyshi
\let\@EveryShipout@Org@Shipout\pr@shipout% This is the original shipout
\let\pr@shipout\@EveryShipout@Shipout%
\fi
}{}%
}
```

> 

What else? I applied the patch to `pgfutil-latex.def` and, at least for my example, everything is OK...