# MacTex 2012 v MacTex2014: Different behaviour combining \PreviewEnvironment{center} and beamer

Tags: beamer, preview

Something changed between MacTex2012 and MacTex2014 in terms of how PreviewEnvironment and beamer interact.

This MWE used to produce a single page (by pdflatex in MacTex 2012), but now it produces two pages, the second blank.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{center}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
test
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to track down why, but perhaps an expert out there can leap to the answer?

[image: MWE rendering produced by pdflatex in MacTex 2014]

Comment: I can confirm that TexLive 2014 on Linux shows the same behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for double checking.  (Perhaps someone has TexLive 2013?)

Comment: The behaviour is the same for TL 2013-2015 inclusive. Both the way the page is cropped and the number of pages produced differs from TL 2012. What I'm not clear about is why this needs to be in a `frame` environment if you are cropping to the image anyway. Is it just a question of wanting the background colour to match?

Comment: Now you've said about the change in behaviour, this is ringing bells. There's something about this somewhere but I can't remember exactly what.... Is [this issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192633/why-is-beamerpstrickspreview-no-longer-compatible-now) related? Does [the corrected patch here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232862/beamer-cls-and-preview-sty-dont-work-together) help? Is `standalone` an option? It has specific facilities for working with `beamer`.

Comment: A commenter (cfr) on the original question correctly identified this as the result of a known bug in PGF, introduced in TexLive 2013, which persists in TexLive 2014. (Not sure about 2015.) The patch described [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232862/beamer-cls-and-preview-sty-dont-work-together), which acts on pgfutil-latex.def, fixes the problem described above.

Comment: @DanielRoy On that basis this is a dupe

Comment: Does anyone know if TeXLive 2015 is still affected?